# CMake: link against static libraries with versions in filename

Tags: linux, cmake, linker-errors

I'm using debian and cmake to build an application in c++. The project is further based on some static libraries ([ITK](http://www.itk.org/)) which are stored in a folder as `libname-x.y.a` where `x` and `y` denote version numbers.

The folder containing the libraries is added to the `LINK_DIRECTORIES` of CMake, and the libraries are added to `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` as `libname-x.y.a`. When building the project with `make`, the linker `/usr/bin/ld` outputs `cannot find -llibname`, i.e., without the version suffix.

The project does not build either when adding the libraries to `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` without the version suffix.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

P.S. on Windows, the compilation and linking works.

Answer (score 2):

> The solution is to use `find_library` and pass the result from that to
>   `target_link_libraries`. This is a bit more work up front but will make
>   the system more pleasant to use.

Taken from *A list of common CMake antipatterns*, section *Using libraries without checking*:

http://voices.canonical.com/jussi.pakkanen/2013/03/26/a-list-of-common-cmake-antipatterns/